# Read in string to user until "." is used

Tags: c, string, input, user-input, stdin

I'm just a bit confused on how I could implement this part of my code.

I need to read in from user a string that could be up to 256 characters. The string should also include any spacing and newline if the user enters it. When the user enters `"."` by itself then it will tell the program that the input is done. After the input is done the program spits back out the exact same string with the same spacing and newline.

For example:

> ```
> Please enter a string: This is just a test.
> The input has not ended yet.
> It will end when the user enters just a period.
> .
> ```

Program returns:

> ```
> This is just a test.
> The input has not ended yet.
> It will end when the user enters just a period.
> ```

So far the only way I can think of doing this is using `fgets()` but I'm not quite sure how to do the check when the input is done with the `"."`. I was thinking possibly a while loop that continuously check?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @levon Please note that the homework tag is now discouraged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag

Comment: @Macmade I am familiar with this .. however, this does not mean OP should not mention this (nor can use the tag) since the way homework questions are [asked and answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is different from other questions.

Comment: you can check string length and if it is 1 or 2, you can check versus "."

Comment: @Macmade E.g., I may give hints and suggestions, rarely will I post complete solution (or for that matter code) for a homework question.

Comment: Hi sorry I wasn't clear. Yes this is homework so if you can only give me hints that will be fine.

What I have tried so far is just using fgets() but from reading around fgets() only doesn't save the newline when the user enters it.

Comment: @user1009706: You'll need a `while` loop, `fgets`, `strcmp`, `strlen`, `realloc` and `memcpy` What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Just possibly some psuedocode. I'm just overall confused, I don't now how to store the newline etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a buffer that you will reallocate everytime there is new data coming in, and keep track of its size:

```
char* data = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
```

Your assumption is correct, you need a loop for this. Something like this:

```
int end = 0;
while (!end) {
    char buf[512];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
        // an error occured, you probably should abort the program
    }
}
```

You'll have to check if the buffer is actually the token you want to end the data input:

```
if (strcmp(buf, ".\n") == 0) {
    // end loop
}
```

If the token is not found, you'll need to reallocate the data buffer, lengthening it by the length of the string you just read:

```
size_t len = strlen(buf);
char* tmp = realloc(data, size + len + 1);   // ... plus the null terminator
if (tmp == NULL) {
    // handle your allocation failure
}
```

...and copy the new content at the end:

```
data = tmp;
memcpy(data + size, buf, len);
size += len;
data[size] = '\0';                           // don't forget the null terminator
```

When you're done, output it and clean up:

```
printf("%s", data);
free(data);
```

Fill in the blanks, assemble, and you'll have a working, safe program, that does what you asked.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! I edit it so it worked perfectly to what I needed!
Thanks again!!!!!